# USB debugging enabled on phone, but can't debug apps

Tags: custom-roms, usb-debugging

I am using a custom ROM on my device (MIUI), and I have enabled USB debugging in Settings, but still, when I connect my phone to my laptop and try to debug apps, it is not showing my device.

This is not an issue with other custom ROMs. I am facing this problem in MIUI only. Any workaround on how to enable USB debugging, without flashing another ROM, as this one serves my purpose correctly (only USB debugging not working).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you see nothing in `adb devices` command's output? Does it throw any error in this command? Which Android version are you using? Also mention which OS on PC you're using for this?

Comment: Yes, in adb devices, it doesn't show my device. No error is thrown. Using android 4.4.2 and Windows 8 on my laptop.

Comment: Does your computer see the phone at all, or is it just `adb` that doesn't see it?

Comment: @aij I can see my phone connected,  but its not listed in adb devices.